# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined in React Native Debugger

Tags: react-native

react native 0.17
Ubuntu 14.04

I Just updated my react native version 0.16 to 0.17 then I try to connect my chrome debugger but I getting this error: --

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

in chrome console

Comment: Have you tried to trace the error back to gain a bit more information on what it is trying to call apply on?

Answer (score 1):

This can cause due to several reasons.

- This can occur due to peer-dependencies which are not compatible with your current react-native version.

Solution for this could be upgrading react-native using `react-native upgrade`, or changing the module or the peer-dependency to a    compatible one with your react-native version

- This can occur, if you are not using redux dev tools for Google Chrome.

Solution is to add redux dev tools ([Issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1114)).

- Some issue with your implementation. Somewhere in your code must have a bug that you would not note and that will give the undefined error.

Solution is to check where and when this exception is thrown out and    find the bug

For more readings [Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4916)